# Searching for a tag within a game object and then playing a sound

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two different empty `gameObjects` which the `currentweapon` gets instantiated into, which one is dependent on the gun as they need to be in different positions. I want to search for certain `tags` within the two empty `gameObjects` and if an `object` within them has that `tag`, play that specific gun sound. There is two problems however, the awp gun does not get instantiated into the correct empty `gameObject` and the gun sounds do not play.

`WeaponManager` script where the gun is assigned to a gun holder (the empty gameObject):

```
[SerializeField]
    private Transform tecweaponHolder;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform awpweaponHolder;

    [SerializeField]
    private PlayerWeapon primaryWeapon;

    [SerializeField]
    private PlayerWeapon secondaryWeapon;

    private PlayerWeapon currentWeapon;
    private WeaponGraphics currentGraphics;

    private Transform currentHolder;

    void Start ()
    {
        currentHolder = awpweaponHolder;
        EquipWeapon(primaryWeapon);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("WeaponSwitch") >0f)
        {
            currentHolder = tecweaponHolder;
            EquipWeapon(secondaryWeapon);
            Debug.Log("switched weapon");
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("WeaponSwitch")<0f)
        {
            currentHolder = awpweaponHolder;
            EquipWeapon(primaryWeapon);
            Debug.Log("switched weapon back");
        }
    }

    public PlayerWeapon GetCurrentWeapon ()
    {
        return currentWeapon;
    }
```

The `PlayerShoot` script which searches for the tag and plays the appropriate gun sound:

```
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform tecweaponHolder;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform awpweaponHolder;


    void Start ()
    {
        if (cam == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("PlayerShoot: No camera referenced!");
            this.enabled = false;
        }

        weaponManager = GetComponent<WeaponManager>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        currentWeapon = weaponManager.GetCurrentWeapon();

        if (PauseMenu.IsOn)
            return;

        if (currentWeapon.fireRate <= 0f)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                Shoot();
                foreach (Transform child in tecweaponHolder)
                {
                    if(gameObject.tag == "Tec")
                    {
                        CmdPlayTecShootSound();
                        Debug.Log("tec sound played");
                    }
                }
                foreach (Transform child in awpweaponHolder)
                {
                    if(gameObject.tag == "Awp")
                    {
                        CmdPlayAwpShootSound();
                        Debug.Log("awp sound played");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if(gameObject.tag == "Tec")
```

with

```
if(child.gameObject.tag == "Tec")
```

And replace

```
if(gameObject.tag == "Awp")
```

with

```
if(child.gameObject.tag == "Awp")
```